# What is the correct logical statement for the statement?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

If 
Number(x):x is a number.
Real(x):x is real.

For the statement "Some numbers are not real."

I found the logical statement to be for some x,(No(x)^ not Real(x)).I have a confusion as to why it is not for some x,(No(x)=> not Real(x))?
`

Comment: This depends on your domain of discourse. If your domain contains only numbers, then the two statements proposed are equivalent. If on the contrary there exists some x such that x is not a number, then the first one may not be satisfied while the second is satisfied by this x that isn't a number.

Answer (score 1):

"Some number is not real." is the same as "Some thing is a number but not real." which clearly corresponds to the correct logical statement with "$\land$".

Comment: As to why it is not the other one, it would be better if you explain why you think the other one works. Specifically, rewrite it in English and see whether it conveys the intended meaning or not.